# Dropdownlistfor in MVC, is not showing full selected value during form submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

I am using dropdownlistfor in view. During form submit, i am returning the model data. In screen, I am able to see the selected value in dropdownlistfor but last char is removed.

For eg: I am selecting "Consolidate" in dropdownlist but getting only "Consolidat" after form submit.

in View,

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedConReportType, @ViewBag.ReportTypeList as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class = "styled-select" })
```

Comment: can you post your action?

Answer (score 0):

Without further info, I'm going here for a guess...

Answers shouldn't be guesses... but questions shouldn't be so short on information neither... so I think we're even.

I think your server is cutting the received info somehow. Maybe you're storing it on a data type with determinated length, or you'are applying it some previous process that strips it.

Check your server code.